# what is the suitable dependency of facebook login for build version 26 in android? I am getting an error for newest versions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

[image: image description here]
This is an image of my `build.gradle` file of the app level and is it's clear, I am getting some compatibility error.

I tried a few different dependencies for facebook login but I got the same error and neither am I able to find a proper documentation with information of proper dependency for every build version.

Comment: Please edit your question to put the code in as text not as an image. Nobody is going to help you if you make the code hard to read. You should also paste your error.

Comment: you have to change it with 27.0.2 and all other support libraries should be same version as implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2' and of course your build version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this before** `dependencies`

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion "26.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this wiped out the error but I can't really understand what this code has done ? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: One of your dependenices is using `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2`,by doing this you are forcing android system to use exact version for all support libraries,except `multidex`,because it is the only support library of the "com.android.support" group that use a different version identifier